# Volumes with Cross Sections, Circle Base and Square Cross Section

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, cross-sections

The base of a solid is a circle centered at the origin with a radius r, and every plane section perpendicular to a diameter is a square. What is the volume of the solid?

So this would usually be easy to solve, but they don't actually give any numbers. I think the equation of the circle here is $x^2+y^2=r$, which should equal to $y=2\sqrt{2-x^2}$, but I'm not sure if this is correct or where to go from there.

Comment: It was a good guess but the equation of a circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. And even better, you were right to double the $y$ at the end of your work, because that gives you the true sidelength of the square. So if that is the sidelength, then what is the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the volume, you 'add up' all the 'infinitely small' areas - in this case squares. This [image here](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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) will give you an idea of what is happening. Taking the limit of this adding process, you get an integral. So What we have is
$$
\int A(x) \;dx
$$
where $A(x)$ gives the area of the square at $x$. This way the integral does the 'adding' and the integrand is what is being added - the areas - to obtain the volume. Now all we need is the limits and $A(x)$. We know that the base is a circle, which as you noted is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. A side of the square will lie in the plane where the circle is. So say you are at $x$-value $x=a$. Then you know that $y= \sqrt{r^2-a^2}$. Or generally, $y= \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. But that's only half the length of a side, so the side of the square is $2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. But we know $A(x)=s^2$, where $s$ is the length of a side. So
$$
A(x)= s^2= \left(2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right)^2= 4(r^2-x^2)
$$
We just need to 'add up' all the possible squares, i.e. find out limits of integration. We need to go across the possible $x$ values for the circle, which are from $-r$ to $r$. So we have
$$
V= \int A(x) \;dx= \int_{-r}^r 4(r^2-x^2) \;dx
$$
Which I will leave as for you as practice to integrate out.